# sql Optimize table valued function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, query-performance, sql-server-2016

I'm working with functions in SQL for the first time and I need a help with optimization. I am using SQL Server 2016.

My function returns a table variable with a comparison of planned and done hours of employees at different projects in every month of a year. But the problem is that the query is loading about 30,000 rows for 30-40s. I've checked some advice about optimization of a query, but I cannot find anything wrong in my code. Could you give me some advice how to optimize it?

The entire function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnProjectHours(                      
 @Project = '%',                      
 @Task = '%',                      
 @Year INT = 0                                
)                      

RETURNS @temp TABLE                       
(                      
 Year INT, Month INT, Project VARCHAR(20), Task VARCHAR(20),                      
 User VARCHAR(50), PlannedHours Numeric(14,2),                       
 DoneHours Numeric(14,2) id int identity ,                       
 primary key(Year, Project, Task, Month, User, id)                      
)                        

AS                      
BEGIN                      

 SELECT @Year= ISNULL(NULLIF(@Year,0),DATEPART(yy,GETDATE()));                      
 INSERT INTO @t                     
 (                    
 Year, Month, Project, Task, User, PlannedHours, DoneHours                        
 )                      

  SELECT rbh.Year, rbh.Month, rbh.Project, rbh.Task, rbh.User, 
        rbhp.SumPlan AS PlannedHours, rbhw.SumDone AS DoneHours                          

  FROM                       
  (                      
   SELECT                       
    CASE                       
     WHEN DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart) IS NULL THEN rbhw.Year                       
     ELSE DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart)                      
    END AS Year,                       
    CASE                       
     WHEN DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart) IS NULL THEN DATEPART(mm, rbhw.Date)                       
     ELSE DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart)                       
    END AS Month,                       
    dbo.wusr_fn_cut(mn.Number, '/') AS Project, ml.Task,                            
    ISNULL(ll.Login,rbhw.Login) AS User                   

   FROM  dbo.Nag AS mn WITH (nolock)                                         
   INNER JOIN  dbo.Lin AS ml WITH (NOLOCK) ON mn.ID = ml.ID                                         
   INNER JOIN  dbo.LinLogin AS ll WITH (NOLOCK) ON ll.ID = ml.ID                       
    AND ll.LinId = ml.LinId    
   INNER JOIN dbo.sl_Operator AS o WITH (Nolock) ON ll.Login = o.Login                                                                              
   FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Hours AS rbhw WITH (NOLOCK)                       
    ON dbo.wusr_fn_cut(mn.Number, '/') = rbhw.Project AND ml.Task = rbhw.Task                       
    AND ll.Login = rbhw.Login AND DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart) = DATEPART(yy, rbhw.Date)              
    AND DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart) = DATEPART(mm, rbhw.Date)                       

   WHERE (mn.Number IS NOT NULL) AND (mn.Status = 0) AND dbo.wusr_fn_cut(mn.Number, '/') LIKE @Project          
 AND ml.Task LIKE @Task                                     

   UNION ALL                            

   SELECT                      
    CASE                       
    WHEN DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart) IS NULL THEN rbhw.Year                       
    ELSE DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart)                      
    END AS Year,                       
    CASE                       
    WHEN DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart) IS NULL THEN DATEPART(mm, rbhw.Date)                       
    ELSE DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart)                       
    END AS Month,                       
    rbhw.Project, rbhw.Task,                         
    ISNULL(ll.Login,rbhw.Login) AS User                   

   FROM dbo.Nag AS mn WITH (nolock)                                         
   INNER JOIN dbo.Hours AS rbhw WITH (NOLOCK)                       
    ON dbo.wusr_fn_cut(mn.Number, '/') = rbhw.Project                                         
   INNER JOIN dbo.Lin AS ml WITH (NOLOCK) ON mn.ID = ml.ID                       
    AND rbhw.Task = ml.Task                                       
   INNER JOIN dbo.Operator AS o WITH (Nolock) ON rbhw.Login = o.Login                                         
   FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.LinLogin AS ll WITH (nolock) ON mn.ID = ll.ID                       
    AND ml.LinId = ll.LinId AND o.Login = ll.Login                       
    AND DATEPART(yy, rbhw.Date)=DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart)                       
    AND DATEPART(mm, rbhw.Date) = DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart)                       

   WHERE (rbhw.Project IS NOT NULL) AND (mn.Status = 0) AND (DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart) IS NULL) AND rbhw.Project LIKE @Project          
   AND rbhw.Task LIKE @Task                      
  ) AS rbh              

  LEFT JOIN               
  (                  
   SELECT DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart) AS Year, DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart) AS Month,                       
   dbo.wusr_fn_cut(mn.Number, '/') AS Project, ml.Task AS Task,                        
   ll.Login AS LoginLL, SUM(ll.Hours) AS SumPlan              

   FROM  dbo.Nag AS mn WITH (nolock)                                         
   INNER JOIN  dbo.Lin AS ml WITH (NOLOCK) ON mn.ID = ml.ID                                         
   INNER JOIN  dbo.LinLogin AS ll WITH (NOLOCK) ON ll.ID = ml.ID                       
    AND ll.LinId = ml.LinId                  

   WHERE mn.Status=0                             
   GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart),DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart),dbo.wusr_fn_cut(mn.Number, '/'),ml.Task,ll.Login                  
  ) AS rbhp                   
  ON rbh.Project=rbhp.Project AND rbh.Task=rbhp.Task AND                       
  rbh.Year=rbhp.Year AND rbh.Month=rbhp.Month AND rbh.User=rbhp.LoginLL              

  LEFT JOIN              
  (                  
   SELECT h.Year, DATEPART(mm, h.Date) AS Month,h.Project AS Project, h.Task AS Task,                       
    h.Login AS LoginRbhw, SUM(h.Hours) AS DoneSum               

   FROM  dbo.Nag AS mn WITH (nolock)                                         
   INNER JOIN  dbo.Lin AS ml WITH (NOLOCK) ON mn.ID = ml.ID                                                 
   INNER JOIN dbo.Hours AS h WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.wusr_fn_cut(mn.Number, '/') = h.Project                                         
    AND ml.Task = h.Task               

   WHERE mn.Status=0                        
   GROUP BY h.Year,DATEPART(mm, h.Date),h.Project,h.Task,h.Login                  
  ) AS rbhw                  
  ON rbh.Project=rbhw.Project AND rbh.Task=rbhw.Task AND                       
  rbh.Year=rbhw.Year AND rbh.Month=rbhw.Month AND rbh.User=rbhw.LoginRbhw               

 WHERE rbh.Month IS NOT NULL AND rbh.Year=@Year              

  GROUP BY rbh.Year, rbh.Month, rbh.Project, rbh.Task, rbh.User,rbhp.SumPlan, rbhw.DoneSum               

  ORDER BY rbh.Project, rbh.Task, rbh.User, rbh.Month          

 RETURN                      
END
```

The `rbh` subquery gets values of most of columns, like project number, user data etc.

The first LEFT JOIN (`rbhp`) gets the sum of hours that user has planned to spend on a project in definite task and month (column `PlannedHours` in the return table).

The second LEFT JOIN (`rbhw`) gets the sum of hours that user actually spent on a project in definite task and month (column `DoneHours` in the return table).

Comment: Transform the function to an inline table valued function. That might improve performance.

Comment: That is a huge query. How are your source tables? I would start at first optimising their indexing - making sure the fields you are using to join the tables are indexed.

Comment: In SSMS, turn on 'Include actual execution plan'. Run inner query (`SELECT` part) manually (declaring and setting variables properly), look at query plan. Most likely you can see there some very bold arrows - these point you to query parts, requiring optimizing. Often you need to create some (covering) indexes, sometimes change logic a little; using custom functions in `JOIN` conditions can be performance killer also.

Comment: Get rid of the order by...... leave sorting to the final consuming query. Full outer join is expensive then union all then left join all that... also expensive. Nothing wrong is in the eye of the beholder

Comment: Agree with Arvo, often query tuning comes down to the indexing rather than the query per se. As an aside, NOLOCK can be dangerous - if the table is updated in the middle of your query running you can lose rows, get them twice or all sorts of odd behaviour. It should NOT be used just to try and improve performance.

Comment: Thank you guys for tips! Arvo, I'm now trying to understand execution plan  (a long road ahead of me..), but I see it will help a lot. I put new indexes and won few seconds :)

Comment: I analysed execution plan and the biggest cost is shown on one of the steps Index Scan --> Index Spool (Eager Spool). In Index Scan I have a warning: Column With No Statistic. It refers to the dbo.Hours table. Can I do sth with it, what could probably help to decrease the cost?

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem here. You declared a table variable, then created a composite primary key and then do the INSERT to that table variable.

First, if you do lots of DML operation, clustered index is not a good option.

Second, you already had the id column, which is an identity column, why you still need those composite columns as primary key.

I think if not necessary, you can drop that composite primary key, then it will boost your performance quite a lot.

Comment: Unofrtunately it didn't help :( Probably the biggest problem is inside the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Costs shown in the actual plan are estimates based on estimated number of rows and can be totally wrong. Use at least set statistics io on to see which table causes most I/O.

Scalar functions are really bad quite often too, and you're using `wusr_fn_cut` all over the place. You won't see the performance impact of it in query plan or statistics io, you'll need to use for example plan cache for that.

An index spool means that SQL Server has created a temporary index into temp. db because it didn't have a good enough index to use. If you see that, you definitely should try to index the original table so that spools are not needed.

This kind of where clause is also quite bad, because it's non-sargable.

```
AND DATEPART(yy, rbhw.Date)=DATEPART(yy, ll.DateStart)                       
AND DATEPART(mm, rbhw.Date) = DATEPART(mm, ll.DateStart)
```

You should always try to compare the actual values without using functions, like Date >= xxx and Date <= yyy

The default values of your parameters:

```
@Project = '%',                      
@Task = '%',
```

Suggests that you're passing `%` when you don't want to limit with project or task and something else when you do. This can end up in parameter sniffing situation quite easily, when you're going to be using totally wrong plan because it was optimized for different case -- since you're also using your parameters with like + scalar function, you're not even going to have very good index usage in any case. It might help if you split your query up into smaller pieces and use temp. tables, but that requires understanding of your database and also testing how it behaves.